# Deploy multiple configurations from command line without changing project files

Tags: msbuild, web-deployment, msdeploy, webdeploy

Please don't be too harsh, because I do not grasp this entirely correctly still, but msbuild/msdeploy is giving me some headaches lately.
Hopefully someone can provide a textual aspirin of some kind? So here is what I want to do:

- I have a web application project, that has multiple configurations, thus multiple web.config-transforms.
- I would like to deploy this project from command line.
- I would rather not want to modify its project file. (I want to be able to do this for several web applications so as least as editing as possible is much appreciated)
- I would like to be able to build it only once and then deploy the different configurations from it.

So far I deployed from command line using something like this:

```
msbuild D:\pathToFile\DeployVariation01.csproj
        /p:Configuration=Debug;
        Platform=AnyCpu;
        DeployOnBuild=true;
        DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish;
        MSDeployServiceURL="localhost";
        DeployIisAppPath="DeployApp/DeployThis01";
        MSDeployPublishMethod=InProc
```

And this performs just what I want, except it only deploys the "Debug"-Configuration.
How can I, with minimal adjustments, make it deploy my other configurations as well?

I was thinking maybe I could build a package that includes all my configurations and then deploy from that and decide "while deploying" which configuration to deploy?
Unfortuanetly I am pretty much stuck here, the approaches I have read about all seem to require some modifications to project files, is there a way around that?

UPDATE:
I am still not really where I want to be here :).

But I looked into this [PackageWeb-approach](http://sedodream.com/2011/12/24/PackageOncePublishAnywhere.aspx) (also interesting video about that [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LvUJFI8CzM)) and it seems pretty nice; I can now build a package that includes all my transforms and then deploy from that as often as I want into multiple configurations.

One thing that I dislike about this is that I have to store my password in plain text into the generated parameters file for the powershell script, does someone know a way around this, I really would rather have that being an encrypted password.

Also other approaches to solve my original problem are still appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same problem and am taking two paths using [Microsoft Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) or MSDeploy which is now in version 3.0.

I first compile the project using MSBUILD using the Package target passing in system.configuration, system.packagelocation. The Package Target generates a set of package files including a {PackageName}.SetParameters.xml file. The SetParameters.xml file by default allows on-publish changes to ConnectionStrings without recompiling when using msdeploy.exe to publish the file. The publish transformation process can also be customized by adding a parameters.xml file to the process defining additional parameterized web.config settings which can be changed at deploy time.

After the initial build I use the {PackageName}.deploy.cmd file generated by MSBUILD during the Package process to deploy the package to the target website. The Package process essentially duplicates the process you are currently doing from MSBUILD in that I can publish one Build-Configuration web.config transform from one compile. The process provides a consistent deployment process that can target remote servers from a central CI environment, which is great from a purely deployment process. The PackageBuild/Deploy process is parameterized within TeamCity, requiring changes to only a few parameters to setup a new deployment.

Like you, I cannot, however, compile a single version of code and deploy to multiple servers using the process as it exists today - which is my current focus. I want to parameterize the transform in a Continuous Deployment, build-once-deploy-many pattern to Dev, QA, User Testing, Staging, and Production.

I anticipate using one of two methods:

1. Create a Parameters.xml file for each project defining the variable deployment parameters along with a custom {ServerName}.SetParameters.xml for each target deployment, both to be used in conjunction with msdeploy.exe.
   a. I am not sure defining a parameters.xml is a flexible enough process for my needs as the current project inserts and removes a variable number of web.config settings. Implementing a parameters file incorporating all of the variables could be too complex for my taste. I would also end up creating all of the target transformations, instead of the current developers initiated process. Not ideal.
2. I am following up on very recent updates to VS2012 Web Tools 2012.2 which allow tying a web.config transform to the publish profiles (profile.pubxml) now stored under SolutionName/Properties/PublishProfiles in VS2012.

VS2012 release 2012.2 adds the capability to create a second transform tied to the publish profile. The resulting transform process first runs the build configuration transformation, followed by the publish transformation, i.e. Release Transform followed by TargetServer Transform. Sayed Hashimi has a great [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdPK8mxpKEI) demonstrating the entire process using MSBUILD.

What is not entirely clear is whether the second transform is supported separately from the build using MSDeploy in a Continuous Deployment, build-once-deploy-many Pattern, or if the publish transformation is only supported during a separate Package/Build for each target transformation.

Option 1 will definitely work for some environments and was my first plan for tackling a Continuous Deployment process. I would much rather use Web Transforms to accomplish the process if possible.

An outside third possibility is using one of several CodePlex commandline projects that are capable of transforming web.config using the XDT transform engine. Unfortunately, using these tools would mean splicing the results into the Build/Package MSBUILD process in order to get the resulting web.config transformation into the deployment package - something I've not yet been successful in accomplishing. Sayed Hashimi also has a PackageWeb project from 2012 that might work as well. I am hoping his more recent work replaces the need for the extra steps involved in the packageweb solution.

Let me know if you decide on a solution - as I am definitely interested.